# The right way to wrap block of lines in custom text in vim

Tags: vim

I would like to be able to select several lines using `vim` when editing an HTML file, then enter some hotkey and get these lines wrapped in a django comment block.

For example, I have:

```
one line
another line
```

I want to get:

```
{% comment %}
one line
another line
{% endcomment %}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the following mapping set up to quickly disable a block of C++ code using `#if 0...#endif`

```
:vmap 0 V'<O#if 0<Esc>'>o#endif<Esc>
```

What this does is set up a mapping that only works while Visual mode is enabled (`vmap`), which disables visual mode (`V`), goes to the beginning of the last visual selection (`'<`), enters a new line above it (`O`), enters the "#if 0" text then quits edit mode (`<Esc>`), then goes to the end of the last visual selection (`'>`), adds a line below (`o`) and enters the "#endif" text.

You could do something similar by replacing the start and end text, e.g.

```
:vmap 0 V'<O{% comment %}<Esc>'>o{% endcomment }<Esc>
```

Note that this requires the use of line-by-line visual mode, entered with a capital `V`, rather than character-by-character visual mode that uses a lowercase `v`.

Comment: It works! Thank you for simple clean solution.

Comment: I've tried to use your solution for character visual mode and failed. If I use v and select some chars and press EscEsc and  press '< or '> (in both cases) I get on first non-space character of line where I've selected some characters.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this does not work for character visual mode, it is after all a line-based operation.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe worth to take a look to this vim plugin http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697